# IValueConverter not working with Designer

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, ivalueconverter

Having this `IValueConverter` does the job perfectly at run time however it does not seem to work with the designer

```
public class NameToUriConverter : IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        if (Enum.IsDefined(typeof(Enumerations.RelicTypes), value.ToString())) return new Uri("/Assets/RelicIcons/Relic_" + (value).ToString() + ".png", UriKind.Relative);

        else return new Uri("/Assets/Placeholder.png", UriKind.Relative);
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        throw new NotSupportedException();
    }
}
```

I am using it as follows:

```
<Image Source="{Binding Type, Converter={StaticResource NameToUriConverter}}"/>
```

is there anyway to make this work at design time as well?

EDIT: I attached a debugger to the VS process so I can debug the `IValueConverter` at design time. The converter returns this string

> "/Assets/RelicIcons/Relic_Lith.png"

if I replace that directly in the XAML code as so

```
<Image Source="/Assets/RelicIcons/Relic_Lith.png"/>
```

everything works as expected. That makes me think that there is something wrong with how the designer handles the Binding expressions. I don't know if I should pass back a `Uri` or a `string` or something else. Based on MSDN the source property should be set to either a `Uri` or a `string`.

EDIT: Debugging Nkosi's answer this is how the Locals of the converter look like [image] I also opened the Solution explorer to verify that the file path is correct

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the following. It converts the URL to an image source for the image. At run time there are other things going on that converts the URL to a proper source for the image control.

Refactored your converter to this...

```
public class NameToUriConverter : IValueConverter {
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture) {
        Uri source = value as Uri;
        var path = Enum.IsDefined(typeof(Enumerations.RelicTypes), value.ToString())) 
            ? string.Format("/Assets/RelicIcons/Relic_{0}.png", (value).ToString())
            : "/Assets/Placeholder.png";

        try {
            source = new Uri(path, UriKind.RelativeOrAbsolute);
        } catch {
            source = new Uri(path);
        }

        var img = new BitmapImage();
        img.BeginInit();
        img.UriSource = source;
        img.EndInit();

        return img;            
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture) {
        throw new NotSupportedException();
    }
}
```

also it is possible that the issue is associated with the path to the resource. At run time the path would be resolved properly but at design time the location of the image may not be located the same way. look into the location of the images at design time. To prove it manually set a path on the control at design time and monitor the path that works. modify the  converter with a similar path and see if it works.

Comment: Nope, this does not work at run time as well. I can confirm that hardcoding a with the path that is supposed to come out of the value converter works properly at design time, so the resource is there. Also I have two questions about your solution? if var is used for a path why do you put `UriKind` in there, and why have you put it to return a `BitmapImage` rather that a `Uri`

Comment: @GeorgeAnastasov I return a BitmapImage because of this. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.image.source(v=vs.110).aspx The string/URL you enter in teh designer is converted to an image source under the hood.

Comment: @GeorgeAnastasov the `UriKind` in the path code was a typo when I copied your original code. I've updated it since.

Comment: I see, I toyed with it and that thing still does not want to work. I will update the question with the debug information

Comment: I uploaded the image with the locals of the value converter. Check it for yourself. I do not see anything wrong with it.

Comment: @GeorgeAnastasov is that at run-time or design-time? notice all the errors where it cannot find the directory of the image uri source?

Comment: this is design time. I have a second instance of visual studio with the same project opened and attached a debugger to the first one. This happens when I write the `Binding Type, Converter={StaticResource NameToUriConverter}` as `Source` for the `ImageControl`

Comment: @GeorgeAnastasov, Ok this is good. understand this. at run time the binaries and content are copied to bin. the location of the images in relation to the executing binary allows the constructed path to be correct. at design time the constructed path is no longer valid. looking into reason.

Comment: I see. The files are currently found in SolutionFolder/ProjectFolder/Assets if that makes any difference. So what I understand is that the paths to the resources is different during run time and design time and I need to separately specify the design time location.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/139079/discussion-between-nkosi-and-george-anastasov).

Comment: This does the trick if it is implemented in a new project. So it is a solution the actual problem. However now I have to figure out why it does not work in my project